# How to update VS Code on Ubuntu 16.4?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

My VScode is asking for  update so I downloaded the zip version of VS Code from the https://code.visualstudio.com/download for Ubuntu but after changing the file am still getting the old version of VS Code.

How can update this VS Code installation? I also tried with command line but unable to update it.

How cab I use the .deb version, or if I use it, would the same process be needed everytime?

Comment: Why were you unable to do it by command line? With just `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` it should work.

Comment: I tried this function but it didnt update the vscode.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a classic `sudo dpkg -i code_1.38.0-1567547996_amd64.deb` after downloading the deb file. Seems to work

Comment: This worked for me perfectly. Thanks Jonas

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "Help" menu & then **"Check for Updates..."**?

[image: Screenshot]

This triggers an update if one is available so you might be able to update your VSCode that way.

Comment: tried this one, it redirected to vs code download page which is not working for me.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be any problem Rohit. I have done the same. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and VS code is installed on my machine, and I downloaded the `.deb` file. Closed the VS code and used this command `sudo dpkg -i code_1.38.0-1567547996_amd64.deb`. The name of your `.deb` file can be different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and this worked perfectly for me:

```
$ wget https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/linux-deb-x64/stable -O /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb
```